# Using BeautifulSoup Python to extract Player Names from </td>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of players here at https://classic.warcraftlogs.com/guild/rankings/615274/latest and I would like to put all of them into the list, playerName. Specifically from the 'Damage Dealers' table.

There's also a class I found in the HTML called 'character-metric-name' that I've tried to mess around with the 'class_' call but was unable to produce any results.

I can't seem to figure out how to extract those names with the code I have. I believe that I'm not using append correctly? Any help is appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
from pprint import pprint
    
parses = "https://classic.warcraftlogs.com/guild/rankings/615274/latest"

p = requests.get(parses)

parse = bs(p.content, "html.parser")

playerName = []

for b in parse.find_all("td"):

    playerName.append(b.string)


pprint(playerName)
```

Comment: Contents are dynamically loaded when you refresh the site and scroll down it is written as loading data so it can't be extract from `bs4`

Answer (score 0):

You are finding all the 'td' elements. On the website, the names of the players have a specific class under 'td' which is 'character-metric-name'. You will have to get a list of all the values under that class. You can find out how to do that online, it should be very easy. Then you can use a for loop to extract the player names.

```
parse.findAll('td',{'class':'character-metric-name'}
```

Comment: So basically with what you gave me I just need to find a way to use playerName.append()?

Comment: Yes absolutely. What you may want to do is first print out what you get with the code I gave you to see if you are getting the correct list. If you are, you can do the exact for loop you were doing before to append the players' names to the list. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I've tried printing out from the code that you gave me and I have reason to believe that the class 'character-metric-name' just doesn't have anything in it. Using findNames = parse.findAll('td',{'class':'character-metric-name'})  .... print(playerName[0]) returns nothing

Comment: Yes I have found the error. Give me sometime I will try and send updated code here

Comment: I think due to the javascript and other stuff, you'll have to do something else. I remember reading that if there is a lot of js, you'll have to do some other process. Sorry, I am not able to extract the names